# Textarea: problem in Opera -- text does not get wrapped onto the next line?

Tags: html, textarea

I do not want the scroll bars,hence i've given `overflow:hidden`.

A simple text area:

```
<textarea cols=10 rows=2 style='overflow:hidden' ></textarea>
```

when opened in Opera Browser -- fails to wrap the entered text onto the next line when the entered text exceeds the column length (Text gets wrapped onto the next line in every other browser -- FF,Chrome,Safari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-TEXTAREA) spec:

> cols = number [CN]
>   This attribute specifies the **visible width** in average character widths. Users should be able to enter longer lines than this, so user agents should provide some means to scroll through the contents of the control when the contents extend beyond the visible area. **User agents may wrap visible text lines to keep long lines visible without the need for scrolling.**

there is no required there that it must wrap.

and from the [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#attr-textarea-cols) spec:

> The cols attribute specifies the **expected** maximum number of characters per line. If the cols attribute is specified, its value must be a valid non-negative integer greater than zero. If applying the rules for parsing non-negative integers to the attribute's value results in a number greater than zero, then the element's character width is that value; otherwise, it is 20.
>
> The user agent may use the textarea element's character width as a hint to the user as to how many characters the server prefers per line (e.g. for visual user agents by making the width of the control be that many characters). **In visual renderings, the user agent should wrap the user's input in the rendering so that each line is no wider than this number of characters.**

So maybe there you could be right, although I don't know how strict a "should" is in this definition.

But in both cases it's probably by design.

Comment: in order to check the entered text,we get a scroll bar (which i've disabled as i'm increasing the rows of the textarea with JS).But,Even though the overflow is set to hidden -- horizontal scroll bar appears in Opera!!.. I want to know why opera is not wrapping the entered content and giving the scroll bar instead!!.

Comment: @Vivek Chandra I am unable to reproduce this in Opera 11.51 with overflow:hidden defined no scrollbar appears.

Comment: Use the above code and enter more than 12 characters in opera (I'm using 11.50 -- shdnt matter much i hope).in other browsers on the 11th character the text starts from the next line but on Opera -- u get a horizontal scroll bar.it shouldnt be hard to reproduce

Comment: @Vivek With unable to reproduce I mean that Opera is not showing me a scrollbar to be sure I tested with both `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` and `<DOCTYPE html>`. The text is just moving, out of the textarea on the left. It's by the way only with words longer than 10 characters, if I write two words of six characters each the appear each on a seperate line

Comment: Exactly,if the length of the word is 10 or more -- the text just moves and you will not be able to check the 1st few characters entered.But on other browsers even though its a single word(length > 10) it wraps it to the next line.Opera fails to do this -- is there any work around to make sure this enters the next line if word is > 10 characters?

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible.